# log "JmsSession was not properly closed !" in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jms

When I launch my application on tomcat everything is ok.

But when I reach the url in my browser, a warning log in the eclipse console is set hundred times every 20 minutes :

> WARN  JmsSession:509 - JmsSession was not properly closed !

I really don't understand from where that come (maybe from an API ..?) and even less how to fix it...

I use in my JEE application :

- spring 3.2.14
- struts 1.2.8
- hibernate 3.3
- JRE 1.6.20

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: JMS? You using Spring Messaging or anything like that?

Comment: @BoristheSpider i think no...

Comment: nobody got an idea ? :(

Comment: Maybe is related with javax.jms or / and activemq libraries ? i fond those in my pom.xml